# When can we conclude that a function is linear if a functional equation is given?

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f : \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that $$f(f(m)+f(n))=m+n$$

In the solution first the function is proved to be injective.

Next it says $f(f(m)+f(2))=f(f(m+1)+f(1))\Rightarrow f(m)+f(2)=f(m+1)+f(1) \Rightarrow f(2)-f(1)=f(m+1)-f(m)=k$ (say).

Till here I am having no problem.

But in the very next step it says from the above derived expression we can conclude that the function is linear.

This is where I am having problem.
Can anyone explain how can we conclude the above statement?
Could we have made a similar conclusion if the domain and co-domain were real numbers instead of natural numbers ?

Comment: Yes, the conclusion depends on the domain being $\Bbb N$.  You've proven that the difference from one "step" to the next is always the constant $k$.  You can prove by induction, then, that $f(m)=f(1)+k(m-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove by induction on $m$ that $f(m)=f(1)+k(m-1)$.  Yes, this conclusion requires that your domain be $\Bbb N$.